# Issue in swiping the images in jquery, javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, photoswipe

I need to add images that should be swiped right and left, instead getting this error in logcat `10-28 11:48:25.734: E/Web Console(5348): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'PhotoSwipe' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/04-jquery-mobile.html:59`
 
where the 59th line is this `}(window, window.jQuery, window.Code.PhotoSwipe));` which comes under the below code. i have included swiper file and referenced correctly, still not able to get, please help me.

```
(function(window, $, PhotoSwipe){
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('div.gallery-page')
                .live('pageshow', function(e){

                    var 
                        currentPage = $(e.target),
                        options = {},
                        photoSwipeInstance = $("ul.gallery a", e.target).photoSwipe(options,  currentPage.attr('id'));
                    return true;
                })

                .live('pagehide', function(e){

                    var 
                        currentPage = $(e.target),
                        photoSwipeInstance = PhotoSwipe.getInstance(currentPage.attr('id'));

                    if (typeof photoSwipeInstance != "undefined" && photoSwipeInstance != null) {
                        PhotoSwipe.detatch(photoSwipeInstance);
                    }
                    return true;
                });
        });
    }(window, window.jQuery, window.Code.PhotoSwipe));
```

Comment: Where/How is `Code` defined (i.e. added to `window`) ?

Comment: Adding a jsfiddle sample would give you responses soon.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below fiddle and the discussions. It was something similar to your issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/Purus/vBvLK/3/

You don't need to wrap the code insdie Photoswipe function. The below line is enough.

```
var $s = $("#gridView a").photoSwipe();
```

Also see [PhotoSwipe: populate / switch image gallery from localStorage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19959452/photoswipe-populate-switch-image-gallery-from-localstorage)