# PhotoSwipe: populate / switch image gallery from localStorage?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, local-storage, photoswipe

I have been hacking at this problem for two days and just can't get it to work. You can find all files referenced here in this ZIP file: http://mtiaz.com/help/help.zip

In the "./js/custom.photos.js" file, I call Ajax to retrieve JSON data from a wordpress site. In the success function I do several things:

1. Loop through all data received and store all attachments per post returned in the JSON object in **localStorage** through the variable "attachments_gallery" (between 14 - 17 attachments per post).
2. Append one image per post (which represents each photoSwipe gallery)
3. A **#overlay** div element, which holds dynamically generated galleries, is hidden by default. When a user clicks one of the gallery thumbnails, it should display on top of everything, and include a the gallery images in an unordered list. This list is derived from previous localStorage transactions.

Now, the problem starts with getting this following error in the console.log:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Util' of undefined     code.photoswipe.noutil.jquery-3.0.5.js:26

Whether I use the minified or the original script, I receive this error. Despite this, the initial thumbnails load into view through AJAX. However, when I click on any of them, I get this following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'photoSwipe' custom.photos.js:157

I just can't get past these two problems. Can someone help me out? Thanks!

### JS FIDDLE UPDATE

http://jsfiddle.net/Z6V4p/8/

```
photoSwipe
```

Comment: Is it possilbe to replicate the scenario in JS Fiddle?

Comment: here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/Z6V4p/8/

Comment: The value stored in local storage is "<li><a href=\"http://ndcye.org/wp-content/uploads/ndc11-2013_1.jpg\"><img src=\"http://ndcye.org/wp-content/uploads/ndc11-2013_1.jpg\" alt=\"\" /></a></li>".. verif this format

Comment: Yes Purus... that is correct. This is then pulled to populate the #Gallery ul, and then assign photoSwipe to it. Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: I am trying to understand what you actually wanted to do with the images.. just to implement a simple photoswipe or any special requriment? let me know.

Comment: a simple dynamic photoswipe, nothing more. thanks for your help Purus. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Ok.. I will see and get back to you.. But I am wondering why you are using local storage for these.. its not necessary if you want just a simple dynamic photoswipe.. just get in ajax call, and display them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the below fiddle.. I have changed that as per your requirement.. use ajax call to get images and display using photoswipe.

Style it accordingly as you needed. For simplicity, I have not applied any styles.

http://jsfiddle.net/Purus/vBvLK/3/

The simple below code will do magic.

```
var $s = $("#gridView a").photoSwipe();
```

Comment: you solved my problem indirectly. In your own JSFiddle, you used v3.0.4... when I switched to that same version, it worked!! :) I think its a bug with v3.0.5. How can I: (1) thank you? (2) report this?

Comment: You can report the issue at https://github.com/codecomputerlove/PhotoSwipe/issues and I am happy to help you. Let me know if you need any other info.